# Android + Facebook + Hide the facebook screen on application load?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm learning to incorporate the facebook sdk into an existing android application.  I believe I have everything working well, however, my app shows a blank facebook page w/ progress loader whenever my application loads.  Is this intentional?  Can this page be hidden somehow?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("***************");
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    ...
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            /*
             * Get existing access_token if any
             */
            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
            if(access_token != null) {
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }
            if(expires != 0) {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            /*
             * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
             */
            if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

                facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {}

                });
            }
    ...
    //thread is created here to populate listview data
    }
}
```

UPDATE:  I now have the key hash working.  I still see the default facebook page with progress loader before my listview is displayed.  I'm also presented with the Permissions page everytime I launch the app now.

NEW UPDATE:
While logged into the official FB app (on the emulator), when I trace facebook.isSessionValid() from my application I receive "false".  Is this a bug?  Any additional help is appreciated!

Comment: Is that during Facebook logon? It would help if you could be more explicit about what your app is doing at that point / share your code?

Comment: When the application loads it gathers data from the strings xml and populates a ListView.  This action takes place within a separate thread.  The user is logged in, yet I continue to see a facebook loading page before my list is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook.authorize will create a dialog if the device doesn't support one-click-sign-in (in which case it'll take you temporarily to the facebook app). The dialog uses a WebView to connect to a mobile friendly facebook login page and handles everything for you, reporting back through the DialogListener.

Since authorize is called in your onCreate method, it will display the dialog whenever the Activity is first started (and the sesson isn't valid).

Comment: I'm now wondering if even my key hash is working at this point.  I'm testing the example that comes with the android fb sdk and I continue to receive "Login Failed:Invalid_Key" error.

Comment: Your facebook key has to be linked to the certificate that you sign the build with - during development, this will probably be your Debug .keystore. You have to register this with facebook, but I am guessing you've already done that since you have the key already.

I helped a friend with similar issue a while back, will check with him how he ended up solving it.

Comment: weird, so I copied my debug.keystore onto my mac ran the keytool. Copied the hash into facebook and walla, it works...  seems I can't generate a working kh from my Windows 7 machine.